# How to save many  has_many_through objects at the same time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, has-many-through

I have two models related as follows.

```
USERS
has_many :celebrations
has_many :boards, :through => :celebrations

BOARDS
has_many :celebrations
has_many :users, :through => :celebrations


CELEBRATIONS
:belongs_to :user
:belongs_to :board
```

In my controller I want to create the objects from form data. I do this as follows:

```
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @board = Board.new(params[:board])
if @user.save & @board.save    
   @user.celebrations.create(:board_id => @board,:role => "MANAGER")
   redirect_to :action => some_action
end
```

Since the models are joined by the many through is there a way to save them in one time and then produce the error messages at one time so that they show on the form at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.boards << @board
@user.save
```

This will save the user object and the board objects associated with the same command `@user.save`. It will create the intermediate celebrations record also with the `user_id` and `board_id` saved but in your case it might not be useful as you need to set values of other columns of celebrations table

Answer (score 4):

Your method looks pretty standard to me. To answer your question...

When working with an association, the `<<` operator is basically the same as the `create` method except:

- `<<` uses a transaction. `create` does not.
- `<<` triggers the :before_add and :after_add callbacks. `create` does not.
- `<<` returns the association proxy (essentially the collection of objects) if successful, false is not successful.  `create` returns the new instance that was created.

Using the `<<` operator in your case wouldn't get you much since you would still have multiple transactions.  If you wanted all of the database inserts/updates in your action to be atomic you could wrap the action into a transaction.  See the Rails API for details:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: `<<` is not same as create methods. It just adds the object to the array of :has_many association. Then, on saving the user object and the associated objects are saved in the database(provided validations are passed). `create` creates the record and saves it in the database if all the validations passes.

Comment: Is there no way to include some attributes for the join table using the above @user.save << @boards.

Comment: Much appreciated. I am looking too :)

Comment: Currently I am have @user.save and @board.save. Problem is if @user.save generates error messages @board.save is not run so I don't get error messages for that model. I would like to have all of the error messages displayed at the same time.

Comment: @chell...You can use & instead of && for that.if (@user.save & @board.save) for that. You will get both conditions checked.

Comment: Your a rock star! That works great. Only :( I have discovered that I must use User.transaction do. Otherwise some data is written to the database but others are not and that creates problems.

Comment: what i ahve done is  write test the following
if @user.valid? and @board.valid? this raises the error messages without saving the data. Once both pass this I save the models