# Ruby on Rails - many to many association with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to create a messaging system in Rails. The association of users to conversations should be of kind many to many, so that users can have multiple conversations and conversations multiple users. Therfore i created the three tables users, conversation_relations and conversations and a model for each.

the models look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :conversation_relations
    has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_relations
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :conversation_relations
    has_many :users, through: :conversation_relations
end
```

and

```
class ConversationRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :conversation
end
```

My problem is, when i try to assign multiple users to a conversation, the entry in the conversation_relations table is updated instead of creating a new entry.

e.g. (on console):

```
conversation = Conversation.create()
user1 = User.find(1)
user2 = User.find(2)
relation = ConversationRelation.new()

conversation.conversation_relations << relation
user1.conversation_relations << relation
user2.conversation_relations << relation
```

The problem occurs in the last line, because it updates the row created by `user1.conversation_relations << relation` instead of creating a new one. Do i need to change something in the models or is the assignment awkward?

Comment: If you have no plans to do anything with the ConversationRelation model, I'd consider using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association instead.  Read 2.8 [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Comment: `relation` could not belong to both of users

Comment: Please refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218994/how-to-save-many-has-many-through-objects-at-the-same-time-in-rails.

Comment: Please make sure you save the user object after assigning with relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 
`conversation.conversation_relations << relation`

you must use 
`conversation.conversation_relations.create(params)`

With the value returned by the given option you can use now << and the new conversation_relation will be added

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
user1.conversations << conversation
# or
conversation.users << user1
```

no need to do ConversationRelation.new, rails will take care of this