# #RubyOnRails Many to Many relationship not inserting into join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, insert, many-to-many

I'm creating an app while learning how to code in Ruby. I'm making a simple league app where i can create new teams, players, leagues...

I have a team model and a league model and because a team can enter in more than one league and one league can have more than one team they are a many to many association. However, when i create / edit a team it doesnt insert anything into the join table, only changes the other attributes.

The models:

Team Model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
    has_many :teams_join_leagues, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :leagues, through: :teams_join_leagues
end
```

League Model

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :begindate, :enddate, :prizepool, :season_id

    validate :start_must_be_before_end_time

  has_many :teams_join_leagues, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :teams_join_leagues
```

Join TeamLeague Model

```
class TeamsJoinLeague < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team 
    belongs_to :league
end
```

TeamController param function:

```
def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, leagues: [:id])
    end
```

Create function:

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully     created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
 end
```

What i'm doing wrong? it never inserts anything on the join table leaving all the teams without leagues :/

Comment: I believe this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218994/how-to-save-many-has-many-through-objects-at-the-same-time-in-rails Best

Comment: @RandallValenciano i did that on my create function but now gives me an error.

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)
    @team.leagues = @leagues
    team.save


Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming your teams_join_leagues table like this:

```
 create_table "teams_join_leagues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.integer  "league_id"
    ....
  end
```

so in your create team, it should look like this or similar

```
def create
    @league = current_team.teams_join_leagues.build(league_id: params[:league_id])
    if @league.save
        ....
  end
```

Comment: I noticed that while its creating the row on the database, its not inserting the league_id, it creates everything including the team_id, just not league_id :/